# Multible forms on one "page" - Multible submit "block"

Tags: php, mysql

I´ve got multible forms on one page (~30), some with fileuploads.

Each form has its own submit-button.

The strukture is the bootstrap-tab and -collapsebox-design - So you can change tabs without reloading and reach every form in the "control panel".

I tried to run "mysql inject me" (firefox plugin) accedently for ALL forms, result:

Server responsed with Error 500.

Did´nt change anything, had to wait 5 minutes and everything was okay again.

My question is: **How can i prevent fast automatic/user submits of theese forms (serverside)? is that possible in anyway?** So that only one can be submitted every ~ 1 second per user.

Comment: do you have captcha validation on this forms?

Comment: no, the only thing is: You have to be logged in. Then this is the users "control panel". One solution would be to change the tabs to own "sites", but then it has to reload, if oyu want to change tabs...still there would be around 6-7 forms per site....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give a *session* to the user
2. Define a variable in the session named *last-submit* and give it the current time as the value.
3. When the form results comes in:

   1. Check what was the *last-submit* value.
   2. If it was more than *x* seconds ago, then save the *time* as the *last-submit* and respond respectively.
   3. If it was less than *x* seconds, reject the form and respond respectively.

If you want to prevent the robots or scripts, then do the following as well:

1. Add an input field to the form, name it _robo_trap_ and make it invisible to the human-eye by set the style to `display: none`.
2. When the forms come in check if the `robo_trap` has any value or if its default value has already changed. If it was, then discard the form because humans can't see and don't need to fill that up.

For example:

```
<?php

/* User Session */
session_start();

/* Current Time */
$now = new DateTime();

/* First Time ... */
if ( empty($_SESSION['last-submit']) ) {
    $_SESSION['last-submit'] = $now;
}

/* On Form Submit ... */
if ( !empty($_POST) ) {

    /* How fast?! */
    $gap = now->diff( $_SESSION['last-submit'] );
    $gap = $gap->format('%s');

    if ( $gap > 1 ) {

        // good ...

        $_SESSION['last-submit'] = $now;

    } else {

        // bad ...
    }
}
```

P.S. Just a sample code to give you some ideas, I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks, this should help. I used the "Ghostfield" allready in my Contactforms. Seems to help. The lastsubmit-field seems to be a good solution. I´ll try it like this. Thanks you good sir.

Comment: Thank you very much. I´ll accept it in ~22hours. Could have done the script by myself, but thanks. Problem was my brain ;) Didn´t know how to start ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a MySQL table with the user's ID and have a row called 'last_submit' which is a `datetime`.

Update it every time the user submits something.

Then just get PHP to check they haven't submitted something too recently.

Comment: Storing such a thing in the database and query that each time is an overkill, IMO. You can simply achieve the same via User Session.

Comment: It's hardly overkill adding one row to the Users table. A member's last activity is useful information. Also, since the main reason for the question is security, my method means one user can submit one form every x amount of seconds. Your method allows one user to submit multiple forms per second if they simply use different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the other forms submit action temporarily:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(':input[type="submit"]').click(function(){

         var otherButtons = $(':input[type="submit"]').not($(this));
         otherButtons.prop('disabled', true);

         setTimeout(function(){
             otherButtons.prop('disabled', false);
         },
         1000); //disable for 1 second


    });

});
```

In the serverside, you could make a resubmit check as seen in: [PHP avoid browser reposting $_POST on page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889198/php-avoid-browser-reposting-post-on-page-refresh)

Comment: thats not what i meant...that is not the problem - The submit will be handleds by an external file - The user just gets a success or error message and the tab he updated will be reloaded...he can´t submit again by reloading. Edit: What i searched was a server side solution - The js solution can easyly be deactivated...